# Why is Xcode telling me this variable is undeclared?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I am getting the below errors in Xcode, I know I needed to declare `filteredChildren` so I tried adding the line `NSArray *filteredChildren` to the header file but it only made things worse. What code do I need to add to the header to delcare `filteredChildren`?

[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/wkd6](http://snapplr.com/snap/wkd6)

Comment: Can you post the header file too?

Comment: Where in the header did you add it? Please edit your question to show the code with the declaration added. Also, what errors do you get with the declaration added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header should probably look something like this:

```
@interface SomeClass {
    NSArray *filteredChildren; // this should fix the compiler error
}

// If the filteredChildren method is public, add this declaration as well to prevent compiler warnings
- (NSArray *)filteredChildren;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the code but make sure all curly brackets are opened and closed after functions, know this can cause the problem and can easily be done with big projects.

```
int a = 1;
void example () 
{ if (exampleVar = 1 {
a = 2; // not declared error
}


int a = 1;
void example () 
{ if (exampleVar = 1 {
a = 2; // should be declaring
}
}
```

check all header files and class hierarchy to make sure you haven't declared headers or the same class twice, This can effect when you create an instance of a class and make it undeclared.

if this isn't the case then try cleaning/resetting your compiled data.